# Поиск анаграммы Python (Оптимизация)

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

Имеется задание, где нужно найти количество пар анаграмм.Я написал код, с использованием Counter'а, но он работает слишком медленно. Мне нужно , чтобы он до 10 секунд обрабатывал 100.000 слов.

Входные данные:
n - количество слов (от 2 до 10^5)
Каждая новая строка до 'n' слово из 10 латинских букв нижнего регистра.

Пример входа:

```
5
qwertyuiop
twoplussix
poiuytrewq
plustwosix
poiuqwerty
```

Пример вывода:
4

Мой код:

```
def comparing(tmp,stack):
    global counter
    ch = True
    if stack == -999:
        return counter
    for i in range(len(tmp)):
        if Counter(tmp[i]) == Counter(stack):
            counter+=1
            ch = False
    if ch == True:
        tmp.insert(-1,stack)

    counter = 0
n = int(input())
tmp = []
for i in range(n):
    tmp.append(input())


for i in range(n):
    x = tmp.pop(0)
    comparing(tmp,x)
print(comparing([0,0],-999))
```

Comment: Что такое «пары анаграмм»?

Comment: Допустим, есть 3 слова ,  'слово','оволс','слвоо', у первого 'слово' пары: ('слово','оволс') и ( 'слово','слвоо') , у 'оволс' пара: ('оволс','слвоо') , потому что со 'слово' уже есть пара. Я если честно не знаю нормально ли объяснил, если не поняли , то спросите ещё раз попытаюсь по-другому обьяснить.И вывод будет 3

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить в вопрос оригинальное задание

Comment: Решение с Counter выдаст неверный ответ при одинаковых словах на входе, верно?

Comment: Есть хорошее описание решения этой задачи: сперва отсортировать так (горизонтальное движение рукой) а потом так (вертикальное движение рукой).

Comment: Вопрос в том, нужно ли отбросить неуникальные слова перед сортировкой)

Comment: @vp_arth, в строгом смысле слово является анаграммой самого себя. Следовательно, неуникальные слова должны увеличивать счётчик. Если это не так, то придётся добавить ещё одну сортировку по вертикали для удаления дупликатов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведённый код многократно считает одно и то же - счётчики букв в слове.

Однако проще отсортировать буквы в каждом слове - получается ключ для поиска, и посчитать одинаковые ключи- да хоть тем же Counter

```
from collections import Counter

n = int(input())
cn = Counter()
for i in range(n):
    s = "".join(sorted(input()))
    cn[s] += 1
res = 0
for x in cn:
    t = cn[x]
    res += t*(t-1)//2
print(res)
```

Comment: Спасибо , работает :)

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter


def input_words():
    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
        yield input()

def solve(word_iter):
    uniqueness = set()
    counter = Counter()
    for word in word_iter:
        if word not in uniqueness: # Не рассматриваем дубликаты
            uniqueness.add(word)
            key = ''.join(sorted(word))
            counter[key] += 1
    result = 0
    for key in counter:
        r = counter[key]
        # Кол-во сочетаний = r! / 2 (r-2)!
        result += r*(r-1)//2

    return result
# cnt = solve(input_words())
cnt = solve([
    'qwertyuiop',
    'twoplussix',
    'poiuytrewq',
    'plustwosix',
    'poiuqwerty',
    'poiuqwerty', # duplicate
])

print(cnt) # 4
```

Comment: Спасибо , работает :)

Comment: Выходит я так и не узнаю, нужно ли было избавляться от дубликатов =)

Comment: Не заметил , что вы спрашивали, я не знаю как лучше обьяснить, я лучше приведу пример. Есть буквы twoplussix, plustwosix , sixplustwo , берём первое слово на стак , получаем пары : (twoplussix,plustwosix),(twoplussix,sixplustwo ),(twoplussix,sixplustwo), убираем twoplussix т.к. с ним все возможные пары уже сделаны. И далее делаем тоже самое , пока не вычислим количество пар.

Comment: Например, если слова 'aba', 'aab', 'aba' - это одна пара или три?

Comment: А , если вы это имели ввиду , то каждая строка уникальная, значит не может быть два раза aba.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось решить задачу без дополнительных модулей, по примеру автора выше.

```
n = int(input())
d = {}

for i in range(n):
    s = "".join(sorted(input()))
    if s not in d:
        d[s] = 1
    else:
        d[s] += 1
res = 0
for i in d:
    res += d[i]*(d[i]-1)//2

print(res)
```

Comment: `elif s in d` это просто `else`

Comment: Ну да , else разве быстрее?

Comment: Отсутствие оператора in быстрее его присутствия, ага

Answer (score 0):

```py
text=["car", "arc", "text", "etxt", "saf","fas"]
text_2=sorted(text)
k=0
n=[]
an = lambda x, y: sorted(x) == sorted(y)
for i in range( len(text_2)):
    if an(text[i], text_2[k])==True:
        k+=1
    
        n.append(an(text_2[i], text[k]))
    elif k==len(text_2):
            break
        
print(n.count(True))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]